# Align text box and textfield

Tags: css

I want to make a form for my react project. I have a text and it's corresponding text field against it. I tried using flexbox but I didn't do it right.  This is my code

```
 <div className="time-from-container">
                        <h4 style={styles.fontStyle}>From : </h4>
                        <TextField
                            id="time_in"
                         
                            underlineFocusStyle={{borderColor: '#293C8E'}}
                            floatingLabelFocusStyle={{color: '#293C8E'}}
                            style={{width: 120}}
                            value={this.secondsToHms(this.props.new_marker_reducer.start)}
                            floatingLabelText="Start Time"
                        />
                    </div>
                <div className="time-to-container">
                    <h4 style={styles.fontStyle} >To :</h4>
                    <TextField
                        id="time_out"
                       
                        underlineFocusStyle={{borderColor: '#293C8E'}}
                        floatingLabelFocusStyle={{color: '#293C8E'}}
                        style={{width: 120}}
                        value={this.secondsToHms(this.props.new_marker_reducer.end)}
                        floatingLabelText="End Time"
                    />
                </div>
```

I want to align then like this

[image]

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox and give the `h4` a width

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  align-items: center;
}
h4 {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>From: </h4>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <h4>To: </h4>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Or you can use the `table` display properties to mimic a table layout

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  display: table;
}
.parent > div {
  display: table-row;;
}
h4,input {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}
h4 {
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <h4>From: </h4>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>To: </h4>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.time-from-container h4, .time-to-container h4 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:90px;
}
```

Comment: this won't align then as I want